# jaxws mapping two XML types to one Java class

Tags: java, binding, wsdl, jax-ws

in short, I have a wsdl that I have no control over, and it defines two types which are very similar and fullfill the same purpose:

```
<xsd:complexType name="TypeA_CommData">
             <xsd:annotation>
                 <xsd:appinfo>
                     <jxb:class name="CommunicationData"/>
                 </xsd:appinfo>
             </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="CommunicationPreference" type=TypeA_CommDataPrfComm" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="Telephone" type="TypeA_CommDataTele" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2" />
               <xsd:element name="Facsimile" type="TypeA_CommDataFacs" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2" />
               <xsd:element name="EMail" type="TypeA_CommDataEml" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2" />
            </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>

 ...
 <xsd:complexType name="TypeB_CommData">
             <xsd:annotation>
                 <xsd:appinfo>
                     <jxb:class name="CommunicationData"/>
                 </xsd:appinfo>
             </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="CommunicationPreference" type=TypeB_CommDataPrfComm" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="Telephone" type="TypeB_CommDataTele" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2" />
               <xsd:element name="Facsimile" type="TypeB_CommDataFacs" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2" />
               <xsd:element name="EMail" type="TypeB_CommDataEml" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2" />
            </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

As you see I have tried to assign the same class name to both of these complexTypes, but sure enough, the compiler throws this exception:

```
[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 832 of file:/my.wsdl

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.   
  line 3078 of file:/my.wsdl

[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 3078 of file:/my.wsdl

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.   
  line 832 of file:/my.wsdl
```

Any idea how I could achieve this?
Please note: i used inline bindings here, which I will not be able to do in production. But it shouldnt be hard to port a solution to an external binding file, I hope...

Comment: if you have no access to the wsdl i think there is no much you can do

Comment: thanks for the heads-up. I was hoping it would be possible via external bindings (I know how to do set that up) and some XML-custom-binding-magic...

Comment: If you MUST use that xsd and you cant changeit, maybe you could try a custom mechanism to create the xml by hand and then send it to the destination location (ws,queue,mail,or whatever), but this as you know is a very nasty thing

Comment: yeah, a bit too nasty for me I guess ;) Eventually I might just go with reflection and convert the XML datatypes to a custom "intermediate" class. That why I´d just need to implement the converter twice but not the actual data logic